# Get index of QgsAttributeEditorField from QgsVectorLayer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I have a `QgsVectorLayer` and right now I'm retrieving it's fields like that:

```
for index in layer.attributeList():
        print(layer.fields()[index].name(), layer.attributeDisplayName(index))
```

Now I changed the Attributes Form to "Drag and Drop Designer" defining my own Form Layout.

I need to retrieve the same fields but maintaining the order, which is represented in the QGS project file as `<attributeEditorForm>` element. So I'm looking for the index of these `<attributeEditorField>` elements, or directly use this list (instead of `attributeList`) to get the fields in the order defined in the "Drag and Drop Designer".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the list of field names in the order you have arranged them (using the Drag and drop designer) in this way:

```
qgis_layer = iface.activeLayer()
edit_form_config = qgis_layer.editFormConfig()
root_container = edit_form_config.invisibleRootContainer()

for field_editor in root_container.findElements(QgsAttributeEditorElement.AeTypeField):
    print(field_editor.name())
```